# Is inline SQL still classed as bad practice now that we have Micro ORMs?

Tags: database, sql, orm

This is a bit of an open ended question but I wanted some opinions, as I grew up in a world where inline SQL scripts were the norm, then we were all made very aware of SQL injection based issues, and how fragile the sql was when doing string manipulations all over the place.

Then came the dawn of the ORM where you were explaining the query to the ORM and letting it generate its own SQL, which in a lot of cases was not *optimal* but was safe and easy. Another good thing about ORMs or database abstraction layers were that the SQL was generated with its database engine in mind, so I could use Hibernate/Nhibernate with MSSQL, MYSQL and my code never changed it was just a configuration detail.

Now fast forward to current day, where Micro ORMs seem to be winning over more developers I was wondering why we have seemingly taken a U-Turn on the whole in-line sql subject.

I must admit I do like the idea of no ORM config files and being able to write my query in a more optimal manner but it feels like I am opening myself back up to the old vulnerabilities such as SQL injection and I am also tying myself to one database engine so if I want my software to support multiple database engines I would need to do some more string hackery which seems to then start to make code unreadable and more fragile. (Just before someone mentions it I know you can use parameter based arguments with most micro orms which offers protection in most cases from sql injection)

So what are peoples opinions on this sort of thing? I am using Dapper as my Micro ORM in this instance and NHibernate as my regular ORM in this scenario, however most in each field are quite similar.

What I term as *inline sql* is SQL strings within source code. There used to be design debates over SQL strings in source code detracting from the fundamental intent of the logic, which is why statically typed linq style queries became so popular its still just 1 language, but with lets say C# and Sql in one page you have 2 languages intermingled in your raw source code now. Just to clarify, the SQL injection is just one of the known issues with using sql strings, I already mention you can stop this from happening with parameter based queries, however I highlight other issues with having SQL queries ingrained in your source code, such as the lack of DB Vendor abstraction as well as losing any level of compile time error capturing on string based queries, these are all issues which we managed to side step with the dawn of ORMs with their higher level querying functionality, such as HQL or LINQ etc (not all of the issues but most of them).

So I am less focused on the individual highlighted issues and more the bigger picture of is it now becoming more acceptable to have SQL strings directly in your source code again, as most Micro ORMs use this mechanism.

Here is a similar question which has a few different view points, although is more about the inline sql without the micro orm context:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5303746/is-inline-sql-hard-coding

Comment: Do you think you could rephrase the question in such a way that it isn't asking for an opinion?  Polling for opinions doesn't fit well into the Q&A format of Stack Exchange.

Comment: You can always abstract your "Micro ORM" queries in a separate class, where when necessary you swap the queries being executed as you change your DBMS.

Comment: haven't heard the term "Micro ORM".  do you mean ORMs that don't attempt to completely take over SQL, or is it something different?

Comment: nevermind, after a little googling, it seems to be a .net thing.

Comment: @Javier: A good example is Massive by Rob Conery, which provides more or less the equivalent of Linq to SQL functionality in 400 lines of `dynamic` C# code.  Dapper is the one written by Sam Saffron that this website uses.

Comment: @MichaelT It is an opinion based question, it felt a better fit here than one StackOverflow, most of the questions here are more *open* in terms of responses, look at all the related questions.

Comment: @Javier I have added the .net tag but there are Micro ORM frameworks for many platforms including Ruby and NodeJS.

Comment: I dont particularly find what you define as 'inline sql' to be bad practice in the first place.

Comment: @GrandmasterB: Explain why in an answer.  I've pretty much sidestepped that issue in my answer, since I believe that it is a question of tradeoffs.

Comment: Inline SQL isn't necessarily prone to SQL injection attacks `SELECT * FROM Table Where ID = @ID`, and then setting a value for the `@ID` parameter (in .Net, this would be `IDbCommand.Paramaters.Add`) doesn't risk SQL injection.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

What you are describing as "Inline SQL" should really be called "string concatenation without parameterization," and you don't have to do that to use a Micro ORM safely.

Consider this Dapper example:

```
string sql = "SELECT * from user_profile WHERE FirstName LIKE @name;";
var result = connection.Query<Profile>(sql, new {name = "%"+name+"%"});
```

It's fully parameterized, even though string concatenation is taking place.  See the @ sign?

Or this example:

```
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", 
          new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

which is roughly equivalent to the following ADO.NET code:

```
List<Dog> dog = new List<Dog>();
using(var cmd = connection.CreateCommand()) {
    cmd.CommandText = "select Age = @Age, Id = @Id";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Age", DBNull.Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Id", guid);
    using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        while(reader.Read()) {
            int age = reader.ReadInt32("Age");
            int id = reader.ReadInt32("Id");
            dog.Add(new Dog { Age = age, Id = id });
        }
    }
}
```

If you need more flexibility than this, Dapper provides SQL Templates and an `AddDynamicParms()` function.  All SQL Injection safe.

#### So why use SQL strings in the first place?

Well, for the same reasons you would use custom SQL in any other ORM.  Maybe the ORM is code-generating sub-optimal SQL, and you need to optimize it.  Maybe you want to do something that is difficult to do in the ORM natively, like UNIONs.  Or, maybe you simply want to avoid the complexity of generating all those proxy classes.

If you really don't want to write a SQL string for every [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) method in Dapper (who does?), you can use this library:

https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/

That will get you extremely simple and straightforward CRUD, while still giving you the flexibility of hand-written SQL statements.  Remember, the ADO.NET example above was the way everyone did it before ORM's came along; Dapper is just a thin veneer over that.

Comment: Good examples, I did already mention that you can sidestep the SQL injection via parameters, as this is just one piece of the larger question, have also added an edit clarifying what I am meaning when I use the term *inline sql*.

Comment: I've added some detail to my answer.

Comment: +1 for information on SimpleCRUD didn't know this existed.

Comment: In Java you will find [Mybatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) which is ligther than Hibernate or EclipseLink and. Its way to go is by predefined sentences in XML (instead of hardcoding on code). It also add some interesting features as preconditions to enhance the final SQL. We used recently into a API web that has quite high concurrency and a not complex business and it worked great.

Answer (score 2):

**I love sql**, and couldn't stand seeing it chopped up in string literals, so I wrote a little VS extension to let you work with real sql files in c# projects. Editing sql in its own file gives you intellisense for columns and tables, syntax validation, test execution, execution plans and the rest. When you save the file, my extension generates c# wrapper classes, so you never write a line of connection code, or command code, or parameter or reader code. Your queries are all parameterized because there's no other way, and you have generated repositories and POCOs for unit testing, with intellisense for your input parameters and your results.

And I've thrown in free steak knives... When an expert needs to come and rework your developer's sql, she's looking at a real sql file, and doesn't need to touch any C#. When she goes back and tidies up the DB, deleting some columns, references to missing columns jump straight out as compile errors in the c#. The database becomes just like another project in your solution that you can hack into, it's interface discoverable in code. If the solution compiles, you know that all your queries are working. There are no runtime errors due to invalid casts or invalid column names, or invalid queries.

Lookin back at dapper, which we're still using at work, I can't believe that in 2016 this is the coolest thing in data access. Runtime msil generation is clever n all, but all the errors are runtime errors, and string manipulation, like string manipulation for any other purpose, is time consuming, fragile and error prone. And how can it be Dry to have to repeat your column names in your POCO, which you have to write and maintain by hand.

So there you go. If you want to look at an unkown data-access technology from an unheard of developer working in his spare time (with a young child and lots of other hobbies), **[it's over here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eaf390af-afc1-4994-a442-ec95923dafcb)**.

Comment: You seem to think a lot of your little "innovation," but how is this any different than, say, [ExecuteStoreQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208(v=vs.110).aspx) or [ExecuteStoreCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=vs.110).aspx) in Entity Framework?

Comment: I'm not getting into the EF or SQL debate. My thing is for folk who want to use SQL. So as a way of executing SQL, ExecuteStoreQuery() will fill your POCOs for you, but you still need to define your POCOs, by the look of things? And it does nothing to help you put the sql in a file, or create your parameters. Your query is not discoverable in code, or testable. Deleting columns will not produce compile errors in your application. I could go on, but I fear I'm repeating myself :-) Perhaps you could take 3mins to watch the youtube video. It's in French, turn the sound down ! English coming.

Comment: EF is quite capable of generating all of the POCOs automatically.  What am I missing here? The real innovation of Dapper and Massive is that you don't need POCO's at all; you can just use `dynamic`.

Comment: I know almost nothing about EF. ExecuteStoreQuery() will fill an entity. Will it generate an entity **from the query**. Entities are generated from DB objects (or vice versa), not from queries. If your query doesn't correspond to an existing entity, you have to write your POCO, no?

Comment: That's true.  I'll look at your code when I have some time; that particular capability might prove useful to me.

Comment: In spite of advertising and not answering the question (directly) I must +1 for "Lookin back at dapper, which we're still using at work, I can't believe that in 2016 this is the coolest thing in data access. Runtime msil generation is clever n all, but all the errors are runtime errors, and string manipulation, like string manipulation for any other purpose, is time consuming, fragile and error prone. And how can it be Dry to have to repeat your column names in your POCO, which you have to write and maintain by hand." seriously

Comment: :-) must say I'm gettin sensitive to charges of advertising when I'm putting my best idea freely out there. [Here's](http://geniusorfantasist.blogspot.com/2017/02/the-tool-in-action.html) my latest bit of aggressive commercialism. By the 3 minute mark, you should know if I'm onto something or not.

Answer (score 1):

Parameterized queries as well as the repository design pattern give you full control over what goes into the query to prevent injection attacks.  Inline SQL in this case is not an issue other than readability for large and complex queries, which should be in stored procedures anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to cover all of your points.  You've got a bit of a three-way battle here in that you're simultaneously discussing ORMs vs Sql (procs or otherwise) and then inline vs proc.  However...

## Inline Sql was never bad practice

- You've always been able to safely do parameterization with inline sql.  Stored procedures can be just as susceptible to injection when they use sp_executesql.
- Injection attacks happen with concatenation of uncleansed, publicly accessible inputs, NOT with inline sql.
- The only appreciable gain with stored procedures is an additional layer of security/responsibility (ie grant exec only to the application), which is totally thrown out the window with things like Entities.
- There are a lot of additional benefits with inline sql when it comes to deployments and staging slots (running different sql in parallel).
- [I go over these points in another SO question.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/239571/9798)

## The Sql of today is even better

Sql has gotten extremely powerful.  Cross apply, windowed functions (over/partition by), provide a developer with some really great wayw to select and project data.  That said, I feel like it has ALWAYS been better than the ORM alternatives.  Developers struggle with simple things like left joins in entities for example.  I've always been on the [Jeff Atwood](https://blog.codinghorror.com/object-relational-mapping-is-the-vietnam-of-computer-science/) side of ORMs in that it's not if they will fail but when.

## Languages are now more flexible when it comes to inline text.

Literal and interpolated strings now make it very easy to work with large sql strings within code.

## Being database agnostic is tough either way

The need to be database agnostic is extremely rare.  The likelihood of switching database platforms is even more rare and designs that do this "just in case" break YAGNI rules.

But for the sake of argument, when it comes to simple CRUD, entities might simplify the feature of supporting multiple RDBMs. However, I don't believe that your CRUD business logic and your queries for more detailed projection, need to share the same database access method - they could still use inline sql with different implementations with the same interface.  Conversely, I suppose procs MIGHT let database specific functionality exist in the database assuming you could name the procs the same.